# SQL dialect is not configured Phpstorm

Tags: php, mysql, config, phpstorm, dialect

I'm getting getting warning "*SQL dialect is not configured*" when I write queries in PhpStorm. I'm using MySQL database

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM anvandare WHERE anvandarnamn = '$this->username' AND losenord ='$this->'password'";
```

How do I configure the dialect to MySQL?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `'` between `->` and `password` in `'$this->'password'"` ?

Comment: Also, try this instead: `$query = "SELECT * FROM anvandare WHERE anvandarnamn = '" . $this->username . "' AND losenord ='" . $this->password . "'";`

Comment: It's working! Tack så mycket!

Comment: Glad I could help! Posted it as an answer aswell. Varsågod.

Comment: For those of you who found this question looking for the location to change your SQL dialects in PHPStorm, the setting is in: **Settings => Language & Frameworks => SQL Dialects**. Hope this helps. I'm using PHPStorm v8, but I'm sure it's similar in other versions.

Comment: @Benjam - still works in phpstorm v10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM anvandare WHERE anvandarnamn = '" . $this->username . "' AND losenord ='" . $this->password . "'";
```

**UPDATE - FEB 2017**

Never ever write a query this way (letting user input run as part of the query). If you're not being extremely cautious (sometimes that's not even enough), you're going to be subject to an SQL injection. If you're writing queries this way you should read more about *prepared statements*.

Comment: Looks to me like this is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: We don't know what the OP has done to `$this->username` before this line of code. But yes, I agree.